Does a MySQL replication slave need to be as powerful as the master?
I want to back-up my MySQL server on another server in another location (for data safety). The problem is the other server is half as powerful as the main one.
I don't need the server to be 100% replicated. Even one hour difference would be enough for my use case but I want to be sure I do not loose any performance.
Does my setup make sense?

Half as powerful in what way? RAM? CPU? Disk I/O?...

The main server has 4 vCPUs and 8Gb of RAM while the backup has just 2 vCPUs and 4Gb of RAM.

The replica should be able to handle the same rate of writes as its source, or else it may fall behind. This is called replication lag.
The replica may get a chance to catch up if the writes on the source come in bursts. Even if the replica falls behind, it can catch up during periods of low traffic.
But I've seen cases where the source is handling a more or less constant stream of writes, so the replica falls behind further and further, until it can't catch up.
Also consider that on the source, writes may occur in many threads concurrently. Traditionally MySQL replays those changes in a single thread, which makes it even harder for it to keep up with heavy traffic.
Recent versions of MySQL optionally can execute changes on the replica in multiple threads (but still probably fewer threads than the changes executed on the source).
Also consider failover. If you intend that the replica will become the main instance if the source needs to go down, then a replica server with half power may not be able to handle the traffic that your source server can.

I would also add that replication is not a backup solution.  If someone drop a table, it will be gone on the replica too. So, we should never forget to put in place a good backup strategy

@EricPrévost, I agree about replication alone not being a backup strategy, but that does not seem related to the question about how powerful the replica server is.

If the replica is running late, that means that the master may have to read back data from the log that it wrote a while ago and which is no longer in cache, which may affect performance on the source (compared to sending data freshly written to the log and still in cache).

@jcaron Have you observed this happen and cause a performance issue? I've never heard of that happening, or experienced it myself. I've administered many MySQL instances with severe replication lag.

@BillKarwin If your source has I/O to spare you don't notice it. Only the source is already near its limits can it be a problem. And since it's mostly sequential reads, the impact should be small compared to the usual random I/O workload.

@jcaron If the source server is so overloaded that reading its binary log files causes noticeable performance degradation, then this is a problem greater than replication lag.

In our environment, read-only applications almost exclusively use the slaves. So they probably get more total queries than the master. This is why we have multiple slaves behind a load balancer.
